# USF4 Matchups with M Bison

Tags: street-fighter-iv

What is M. Bison'a best and worst matchup in Ultra Street Fighter 4?

I'm not sure which character I go against gives that I easily fall under pressure. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

On a high level of play M. Bison (Dictator) is considered very good against Blanka and Dan and really bad against Guile. You can check out the "current" Tier list at [eventhubs](http://www.eventhubs.com/tiers/sf4/character/mbison/).

Then again you have to account for

- Difficulty and safety of combos
- Footsie game
- Amount of players (or how good do you know the matchup)
- Priority of normals and specials

Personally, I would consider him an easy to pickup character, because of his good pokes. But it is really tough to play competitive with him. There are hardly any "professional" players that win tournaments with him.

Online it should be easy to beat bad shoto characters, until they understand the concept of "safe" moves and can deal high damage combos.